# I'm inside your house and always have been

Tags: riddle, word

*I'm inside your house and always have been.*

*In the day i'm usually perpendicular to you but in the night parallel to you.*

*You rarely think about me but use me daily - you even have to!*

*I'm five letters long.*

**Who Am I?**

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are

> the floor.

*In the day i'm usually perpendicular to you but in the night parallel to you.*

> During the day we are upright but at night we lay down.

*You rarely think about me but use me daily - you even have to!*

> We have to walk on the floor but we don't think about it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> The **floor**?
>
>  Perpendicular to you during the day, when you are upright, and walking around. Parallel to you at night when you are lying down in bed.
>
>  You have to use it to move around your house (unless you can float), but don't really think about it.